# R won't find libR.so on its own

Tags: r, rhel, ldd

I have recently installed R v4.3.2 on a RHEL 8.7 (after removing an older v4.0.4)
It has been installed using a downloaded rpm and the yum command.

however, R fails to find libR.so if I try to launch it in any way :

- typing R in the command line.
- launching Rstudio
- R shiny apps

**First solution tried : modifying LD_LIBRARY_PATH**

If I modify LD_LIBRARY_PATH to include /opt/R/4.3.2/lib/R/lib, almost everything works : R, R-studio-server,shiny apps.

However Rscript doesn't. I assume it launches in a different shell that doesn't have LD_LIBRARY_PATH (?)

Using Rscript -S --vanilla does work (?) sometimes but then rjava doesn't load properly (does vanilla break something in the JAVA_HOME parameters?)
This was getting to be a headache, so I tried something else.

**Second solutions tried : fixing the path R uses**

I found a similar issue on an old forum suggesting to create this conf file /etc/ld.so.conf.d/libR.conf with those two lines :
/usr/lib/R/lib/
/opt/R/4.3.2/lib/R/lib

Now, I get a different error message that R cannot libRblas.so which is in the same folder.

Last solution I can think of is to reinstall from source to be sure I have the right options like shlib.
I am not a sysAdmin so would welcome suggestions..

Comment: The R binary you installed may have been configured that way so you may have to talk to the maintiner of the rpm package.  For Debian / Ubuntu I use the `--enable-R-shlib` flag for R itself, and similar flags `--with-blas` and `--with-lapack` for these libraries.  So might be best to talk to rpm users via the `r-sig-fedora` list.